# How to run code on the main thread from a new UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm writing a plug-in for an application, in which the plug-in is a .NET assembly. The application calls the `Execute()` method of a specific class in the assembly. My `Execute()` method needs to display a GUI and perform some calculations. These calculations use objects passed into the `Execute()` method. I would like to perform these calculations in the background so as to not block the GUI. However, the objects passed into the `Execute()` method cannot be accessed from another thread (this is beyond my control). Therefore, I can't create a background thread to perform the calculations.

My idea is to create another thread for the GUI and perform the calculations on the main thread. Therefore, the GUI thread will need to access the main thread in order to interact with the application objects. What is a clean way of doing this? I have thought about creating an `Action` queue that the main thread "listens" to as the GUI thread enqueues actions to perform. Is there a better way?

Comment: Don't have a background worker construct GUI objects; have it construct data objects that you can use to quickly populate a UI.

Comment: You say : "However, the objects passed into the Execute() method cannot be accessed from another thread (this is beyond my control)." Are those object win forms controls?

Comment: @Servy Assuming I understand you correctly, the data objects will need to use the application objects passed to the assembly, and these objects cannot be accessed from another thread. Therefore, I don't think I can have a background worker create those data objects.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea The objects passed to the `Execute()` method are not WinForm controls. They are objects defined by the main application.

Comment: @redcurry Why are you confined to the main thread? What kind of objects are those? Do they work with a message pump? Perhaps with a good thread synchronization you could still offload your calculations to another thread. Give more details.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea I'm confined to the main thread because the application calls the plug-in's `Execute()` method in the main thread and the objects passed to it cannot be accessed from another thread. These are the application's requirements (which is a third party application that I cannot change). The classes that I'm working with are defined by the API that the application provides for plug-in extensions. I don't know the full details, but these classes are very complex, like accessing databases and running native code, and that's probably the reason they can't be accessed by another thread.

Comment: @redcurry Then I guess you're out of luck. Creating the GUI in another thread is one thing, but manipulating the main thread so you can synchronize it with your GUI thread... Well, that a whole different beast you don't want to awake. I suppose you don't to suspend the main thread while your GUI is waiting for some user input, do you?

Comment: @redcurry Btw, running all the plugins in the same thread as the main application is at least of poor design. What if some plugin decides to do Thread.Sleep(100000)? That will just halt the entire application.

Comment: @redcurry You could get away with the GUI in a different thread if your GUI was only meant to display some information and you could update it as your calculations progress. But if you were to need user input, I don't see how you could achieve it without suspending the main thread while waiting for the input.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea I agree that the application's plug-in architecture is not very good (the fact that it loads and executes plug-ins in the same AppDomain has already caused me headaches before). What about having the GUI in a different thread, while the main thread waits for actions to be queued by the GUI thread? The GUI needs to be interactive, not just display information.

Comment: @redcurry Imagine the following scenario: Your execute method, which runs in the main thread, reaches a point where it needs value X from user input. In cannot continue without it. Your choices are: abandon the calculations or display the GUI waiting for the user input. However, what will your main thread do in the meantime? Wait, of course... That means suspending it. Is that acceptable? I guess not.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea The thing is that the GUI should be running at all times. Here's the scenario I'm thinking about: The `Execute` method runs, creates a GUI thread and displays a window. The user interacts with the window, entering the necessary input. The users clicks on "Go" and the calculations start (on the main thread, somehow) while the GUI displays a dialog box with a progress bar showing the user how far along the calculations are.

Comment: @redcurry You can't just pick a thread and run code on it, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea Well, that's why I thought about having the main thread constantly read from an `Action` queue (inside a loop until the user quits the GUI). When the GUI needs the calculations to start, it would enqueue an `Action` along with the necessary input. The main thread would then take the next item in the queue and run it, and then go back to checking for more actions in the queue. Would that work?

Comment: @redcurry Of course you could do that... But you main thread would be trapped in that loop for as long as you GUI would run. There's no real benefit. You could as well suspend the main thread.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea There's actually no reason for the main thread to do anything other than to perform calculations, so it's fine if it's suspended. Does this link point me in the right direction for doing what I think you're suggesting? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tttdef8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @redcurry Depends very much  on the specifics of your calculations. If suspending the main thread is not an issue, you can use any synchronization methods currently available. I was think more in terms of EventWaitHandles. Where you would perform some calculations and then wait for a signal from the GUI, do something again, wait again and so on... Again, I don't know anything about the nature of your calculations so I can't be more specific.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea Thank you very much for your help and discussion!

Comment: @redcurry You're welcome!